# withTheme not a function react native error

Tags: react-native

I actually don't know why is this happening. I have some others warning like,
"Error: Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from"
I sharing my error log screenshot and package.json file below. Can anybody help me to get out?

[image]

```
{
  "name": "eonbazar",
  "displayName": "eonbazar",
  "description": "MStore Pro - Complete React Native template for e-commerce",
  "author": "InpireUI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "./scripts/setup.sh",
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@callstack/react-theme-provider": "^2.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "4.1.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
    "@unimodules/core": "^5.5.1",
    "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "~5.6.0",
    "api-ecommerce": "^0.0.36",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "by": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "create-react-context": "^0.3.0",
    "css-select": "^3.1.0",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.6",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.13.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.3",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-ads-facebook": "~8.4.1",
    "expo-analytics": "^1.0.16",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.3",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-localization": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.5.0",
    "firebase": "7.24.0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.3",
    "html-entities": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "monet": "0.9.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "oauth-1.0a": "2.2.6",
    "parse": "github:parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS#master",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-instantsearch": "^6.8.1",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "4.0.4",
    "react-native-clean-form": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "1.5.3",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-dev-menu": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "git+https://github.com/luyx2412/react-native-drawer.git",
    "react-native-expandable-section-flatlist": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-fluid-slider": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-masked-text": "1.13.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "2.0.2",
    "react-native-paper": "4.2.0",
    "react-native-parallax": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.11.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "3.2.4",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.14.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.2",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.63.5",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "6.0.0",
    "react-navigation-props-mapper": "^1.0.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.2",
    "react-proxy": "^1.1.8",
    "react-redux": "7.2.1",
    "reactotron-react-js": "^3.3.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-actions": "2.6.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "required": "^1.0.0",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^3.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20",
    "urijs": "1.19.2",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "url-parse": "1.4.7",
    "util": "0.12.3",
    "uuid": "8.3.1",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1",
    "wpapi": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/types": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-jest": "26.5.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "jest": "26.5.3",
    "reactotron-react-native": "5.0.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecommerce"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading without more code or info, but I had a similar issue. Your problem may be the way `withTheme` is being imported @callstack/from react-theme-provider. Looking a the docs I had some success with changing the way I retrieved the function from the package. If you are importing it like this:

`import { withTheme } from "@callstack/react-theme-provider";`

Try instead to do the following:

```
import { createTheming } from '@callstack/react-theme-provider';
const { withTheme } = createTheming();
```

If you have a `defaultTheme` you can pass it as an argument like `createTheming(defaultTheme)`;